# clone from bitbucket.org in command on guest linux virtual box through proxy in host

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, proxy, git, clone

I am using an ubuntu virtualbox guest on a windows 8 host.
I am going to clone a repo from www.bitbucket.org using git command in guest.
BUT the problem: I realzied that I cannot connect to www.bitbucket.org without using a proxy on my network. so I am using a proxy client on my host for connection.
now I am wondering how can I make my shell in guest, to use proxy server that am connecting my host to it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

git supports proxy through setting the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Try:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyhost:proxyport/
git clone <repo>
```

This is the easiest way. 
For other options see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy.